# How to make Chrome tabs like Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, safari, browser-tabs

Safari's tabs are superb, you can have 100 open tabs and it won't hinder you. (As long as you supply the RAM. :D ) Any way I can have that in chrome?

Comment: I have at least 100 open tabs in Chrome as various points and don't have a problem. What is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: @BradPatton Have you seen how Safari handles the case? It's awesome! In Chrome, tabs are all assigned the same width which makes you not see their titles and make hard to click on them.

Comment: HappyFace welcome to SuperUser. Your original question wasn't clear about the tab behavior. Chrome will easily accommodate lots of open tabs but as you point out the tabs will shrink in size in a single window. I have multiple windows open with multiple tabs per window so I don't run into this as much. This is core browser UI so I'm not sure that an extension could even override it.

Comment: @BradPatton That's sad :((

Comment: Found this extension that will give you searchable drop-down list of all of the open tabs: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb

Comment: @BradPatton You're kind ❤️I already have Tabs Outliner and it works, but it is not as awesome as Safari. Now that I think about it, it's only natural that Chrome doesn't have this ability, as it needs an Apple trackpad. Apple trackpads are so awesome :( I wish other companies reach this technology as well so we could have decent apps optimised for good trackpads.

Comment: Many of us have been wanting the "Expose" or "Tab Expose" functionality of Safari for a long, long time in Firefox/Waterfox and Chrome* browsers. Developers such as Firefox's lead has said that an extension CAN accomplish this, but it simply seems no one has developed such a WONDERFULLY needed extension yet...

Answer (score -2):

In Chrome:

1. Right click on the tab
2. Click "Pin"

Done!

[image: Process screenshot]